# Creating a bot file for a v3 project

Tags: botframework

I've inherited a Microsoft Bot Framework v3 project. I wish to run it locally in a debugger and use the bot emulator to interact.

This is easy with a v4 project, you just open the bot file in the emulator and it reads the config it needs to connect both to the local and the cloud version.

One can also use the emulator to *create* a bot file, so I did, and this allowed me to connect to the bot. However, this bot uses a QnA service, and when I run it locally and connect to it with the emulator, it responds with

> Please set QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey and QnAEndpointHostName (if
>   applicable) in App Settings. Learn how to get them at https://aka.ms/qnaabssetup.

Since these values *are* defined in app settings in web.config,  and they are certainly defined in the botdata table in the cloud, it seems likely that my bot file isn't  right.

Can anyone offer guidance on handcrafting a bot file?

This is what's currently in the bot file

```
{
    "name": "pai46",
    "description": "",
    "services": [
      {
        "type": "endpoint",
        "appId": "da3...229",
        "appPassword": "a password cribbed from the settings on Azure",
        "endpoint": "http://localhost:3984/api/messages",
        "id": "another guid",
        "name": "development"
      }
    ],
    "padlock": "",
    "version": "2.0",
    "overrides": null,
    "path": "D:\\pai46-src\\pai46.bot"
}
```

The reason this looks like a rename of the v3 QnA starter project that you get by creating a QnA bot on Azure and downloading the code, is that's what it is. I decided to work the problem in its simplest form prior to fiddling with someone else's code. Here's some of `web.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <!-- update these with your Microsoft App Id and your Microsoft App Password-->
    <add key="MicrosoftAppId" value="da3...229" />
    <add key="MicrosoftAppPassword" value="same password as bot file" />
    <add key="AzureWebJobsStorage" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=pai46a3ba;AccountKey=base64string;"/>
    <add key="QnAAuthKey" value="00e...fab"/>
    <add key="QnAEndpointHostName" value="https://a-working-qna-service.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker"/>
    <add key="QnAKnowledgebaseId" value="ca7...b3a"/>
  </appSettings>
```

I am using the "Bot Framework Emulator (V4)" because it's the only one I can find on the Microsoft website. Help/About reports version 4.2.1

[image: BFE]]

This is what happens when I run the bot and connect to it and then say "hi" in the emulator.

[image: BFE-please-set-keys]

Comment: Hi Peter! Yay for adopting an old bot, lol! Let's check a couple things: make sure there isn't ANYTHING in your bot file, except the empty 'development' service with the localhost endpoint. A v3 bot shouldn't need it. Make sure your web.config is updated with ALL of the above keys. Can you post a screenshot of your web.config (with the keys blacked out of course) to the question? and how are they being called in the bot?

Answer (score 0):

Bot Files were introduced with v4 of the BotBuilder SDK a few months ago. In v3, you can create a Bot File for your project to connect it to the v4 Bot Emulator, but all of your secrets and keys should still be managed in your web.config.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helps to the extent that you confirm my assumptions, but it doesn't advance my situation. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: What version of the emulator are you using? You should be able to put the keys in the web.config file as described by TJ above, you shouldn't need to 'connect them to the emulator'.